# How can I add custom time line in react native svg charts

Tags: date, labeling, react-native-svg-charts

I am using react native svg charts to display some data on line chart .the data is associated with some time which need to be labelled on x axis can anybody tell me how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

When we look at LineChart, it draws the lines like this.

- It accepts 50 as points and 10 points and draws a line between
- It accepts 10 as points and 40 points and draws a line between

  class LineChartExample extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
  const data = [50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, 85, 91, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80]

  ```
   return (
       <LineChart
           style={{ height: 200 }}
           data={data}
           svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }}
           contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
       >
           <Grid />
       </LineChart>
   )
  ```

  }
  }